# Anaconda directory and anaconda prompt are missing after installation, how to fix it?

Tags: anaconda, conda

I install anaconda conda on windows, but the scripts directory and the anaconda prompt are missing.

Answer (score 0):

For me the solution was to install an older version from https://repo.anaconda.com/archive/

The newest that worked was Anaconda3-2019.03-Windows-x86_64.exe

Before that I tried removing the installation, reinstall it, installing the 32bit at least a couple of times. Nothing worked, except to install the older 2019.03 version.